# Error when generating report from mongodb Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to fetch reprorts from mongodB Azure Cosmos DB
but I got this error any ideas about "Request rate is large"

> [MongoDB\Driver\Exception\RuntimeException]
>     Message: {"Errors":["Request rate is large"]}
>     ActivityId: 3ed9b0b0-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, Request URI: /apps/56e5f1c8-3a07-4d35-974e-aabfdb9d95c3/services/1aead77f-7daf-4dd5-b514-c4694384803c/partitions/a9eb8681-b325-4b62-9601-9d57b325da3a/replicas/131818510503404005p, RequestStats:
>     RequestStartTime: 2018-10-01T11:56:27.9231945Z, Number of regions attempted: 1
>     , SDK: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.0.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Request rate is large" is a CosmosDB error that you will get if your actions cost more data than the provisioned throughput can provide you with.

It means that your collection's provisioned RU/s are less that what your query costs to run in one second. You can get around this by increasing the retry count for these errors in the `IDocumentClient` by setting the `RetryOptions` `MaxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests` property to something higher. This is an object of the `ConnectionPolicy` object used to initialise the `IDocumentClient`.

The other way of course is to increate the throughput of the collection from the portal or your C# code.